# Winkel II fails while reprojecting on the fly in QGIS 3.12

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, coordinates, proj

Currently, in QGIS 3.12 the Winkel Tripel projection working on the fly but Winkel II, which is also implemented, is not working.

This is the fact or there is a bug?

If I reproject dataset into `ESRI:54019` (in QGIS 3.10-12 CRS are named ESRI instead of EPSG), it is working.

[image: map]

When reprojecting dataset to The Winkel Tripel (`ESRI:54042`) it is working well.

Comparisson from here [Compare Projections Winkel II vs. Mercator](https://map-projections.net/compare.php?p1=winkel-2&p2=mercator-84&sps=1) does not really answer my question.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Are you using `EPSG:53019` or `EPSG:54019`?

Comment: I am using ESRI:54019. Exception ”forward transform of (inf, inf) Error: Fallback transform failed” This error occurs when I try to reproject on the fly the Natural Earth ”ne_110m_land” data by setting the project CRS to winkel II, or other data set. Also, polygons appear on screen instead of the data set.

Comment: The OSM layer (and any other layers) from "QuickMapServices" plugin, are not displayed at all. This is happening also with ESRI: 53019

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35512 this will work without issues in any modern QGIS that uses PROJ >= 7.1.

Comment: Which QGIS versions use PROJ>=7.1?

Comment: That depends on your system. It can be different for different operating systems, packages and so on. Current osgeo4w should have it.